# Is there a known bug in iOS8 causing the status bar to overlay apps or web pages?

Tags: ios

I found mention of this with this example (but no more info)

[image]

And we are having a problem (only on iOS8 on the ipad) causing this problem on our website:

[image]

Comment: I found [this](http://openradar.appspot.com/14201871) in a quick search. You can try to find out yourself [here](http://openradar.appspot.com).

Comment: Hmmm that bug is over a  year old and on a beta of the previous OS. So either it's resolved  or it never will be. (not germane to this). Thanks for the list, but I didn't find a similar bug.